# Preventing items in ListBox from exceeding its width

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, itemscontrol, listboxitem

I'm sure this is simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  Basically, I'm trying to force `ListBoxItem` from allowing itself to go outside of `ListBox` width.  For example, let's say we have a crude `ListBox` with a `TextBox` for each `ListBoxItem`:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

If you were to type in them, the text, eventhough it has `TextWrapping` set to `Wrap`, will continue flowing to the right, as the width of the `ListBoxItem` and the `ListBox` adjust to the width of the content (note that the `HorizontalScrollBar` appears):

[image]

I'm sure this is an intended behavior and is probably caused by the `ScrollViewer` within the template, but I want the text to wrap and be contained within the original width.  I can solve this by setting a static width, but it would be a sketchy design decision and not something I want to do (it would restrict things from being re-sized easily).

Basically, the behavior I'm seeking is that of an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image]

I just want to keep the `ListBox` control because of its other behaviors, which I need.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will disable the horizontal scrolling *(even though it sounds like it's only disabling visibility)*:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Worked like a charm.  Thank you so very much.